# Изменение основного контента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сайт с 6-ю кнопками в меню.
Смысл в том, что каждая кнопка меняет основной контент сайта (пытаюсь сделать что-то типо сайта без обновления). Проблем никаких не возникло, скорее неудобство.
Что-бы вызвать новый контент, нужно спрятать возможный предыдущий.
В JS и Jquery не силён, поэтому сделал так:

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
    $("#div1_div").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#div2_div").fadeOut(100);
    $("#div3_div").fadeOut(100);
    $("#div4_div").fadeOut(100);
    // и тд
}) 
$("#button2").click(function () {
    $("#div2_div").fadeIn(100);
    $("#div_div").fadeOut(100);
    // и тд
})
```

Это наверное глупо, не правильно и неудобно для работы.
Как это можно упростить? Как сделать по человечески?
P.S. React + Nodejs просьба не предлагать. Нет времени его изучать пока, сложновато.
P.P.S. Пробовал Fullpage.js, немного не то + платные ограничения.

Comment: Например, подгружать данные через `ajax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Скрытие всех кроме одного
for (let i = 6; i > 1; i--) $("#"+"content"+i).fadeOut(100);

// Запоминаем не скрытый элемент
lastID="content1"

function setContent(id) {
  // Показываем новый элемент 
  $("#"+id).fadeIn(1000);
  // Скрываем предыдущий элемент
  $("#"+lastID).fadeOut(100);
  
  // Обновляем не скрытый элемент
  lastID= id;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="setContent('content1')">
1
</button>
<button onclick="setContent('content2')">
2
</button>
<button onclick="setContent('content3')">
3
</button>
<button onclick="setContent('content4')">
4
</button>
<button onclick="setContent('content5')">
5
</button>
<button onclick="setContent('content6')">
6
</button>

<div id="content1">
  CONTENT1
</div>
<div id="content2">
  CONTENT2
</div>
<div id="content3">
  CONTENT3
</div>
<div id="content4">
  CONTENT4
</div>
<div id="content5">
  CONTENT5
</div>
<div id="content6">
  CONTENT6
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое :)

Comment: Проблемка правда, если быстро прокликать, либо откроются много окон, либо вообще пусто.

Comment: Добавил if($("#"+id).is(":visible")) { return false; } в начало кода и норм)

Answer (score 1):

Более короткий пример:

```js
$("#button button").on('click', function () {
 var key = $(this).index() + 1; /* Index - всегда считается с 0-ля*/
 $("#content div").hide();
 $("#content div:nth-of-type(" + key + ")").fadeIn(1000);

});
```

```css
#content div:not(:first-of-type){
display:none;
}

#button button{
display:inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="button">
 <button>1</button>
 <button>2</button>
 <button>3</button>
 <button>4</button>
 <button>5</button>
</div>


<div id="content">
 <div>Content 1</div>
 <div>Content 2</div>
 <div>Content 3</div>
 <div>Content 4</div>
 <div>Content 5</div>

</div>
```

P.S. Конечно при условии что у вас очерёдность кнопок и контента совпадает(!)

Comment: Спасибо большое :)